# How to load a PDB file into x64dbg?

Tags: windows, x64dbg, symbols, debugging-symbols, pdb

I want to see symbols in the disassembly wherever possible, and I have a PDB file for the .exe I'm debugging, but I can't find a way to load the PDB file from disk. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [symload/loadsym](https://help.x64dbg.com/en/latest/commands/analysis/symload.html) command.

In the x64dbg console type:

> symload pdbconsoleapplication1,symbols\pdbconsoleapplication1.pdb,[0/1]

With the last argument, you can control if the validation of symbols shall be skipped or not (1 - skips).

Comment: Thanks! Could you please point me to where this is documented? I couldn't find it with Google.

Comment: hmm, the `symload/loadsym` text in my answer is the link to x64 documentation page.